# Meaning behind the proof of this lemma used in proving the isomorphism theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Lemma:
>   Let $N$ be a normal subgroup of a group $G$ and let $\gamma : G \to G/N$ be the canonical homomorphism. Then the map $\phi$ from the set of normal subgroups of $G$ containing $N$ to the set of normal subgroups of $G/N$ given by $\phi(L)=\gamma[L]$ is 1-to-1 and onto.

Proof starts as following, and this is exactly the part I couldn't understand:

> If L is a normal subgroup of $G$ containing $N$ then $\phi(L)=\gamma[L]$ is a normal subgroup of $G/N$

Yes, this can easily be shown, since $\gamma$ is an homomorphism, and homomorphisms preserve normality.

> Because $N \le L$ for each $x\epsilon L$ the entire coset $xN$ in $G$ is contained in $L$. Thus, $\gamma^{-1}[\phi(L)]=L$

How did we conclude the second sentence? This is only possible if $\gamma$ is 1-to-1 but that's what I'm trying to prove.

> if $\phi(L)=\phi(M)=H$ then $L=\gamma^{-1}[H]=M$ Therefore $\phi$ is 1-to-1

Same question as above.

Comment: The Correspondence Theorem tells you that. A bit weird using it to prove the Isomorphism Theorem, where did you find that lemma?

Comment: @GilbertoLópez Fraleigh